# Retrieve list of users from Active Directory Group from non owner user logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory

I am trying to fetch users list of particular AD Group but I am not the owner of that group so i am getting null result

I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

Below is my code for fetching group details

```
var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName);
```

Here context is

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com")
```

I had tried both but not working

Comment: can you share the `context` declaration?

Comment: var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com")

I had tried both but didnt work

Comment: try `var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain", "YourUsername", "YourPassword")`

Comment: @VivekNuna not working